# Creating & Updating UserProfiles in Django

Tags: python, django

Django newbie here stumbling my way around the docs. I'm trying to create a user profile using Django's "UserProfiles", but I'm having a little trouble with figuring out the proper way to set the code based on Django docs.

Here's my code, based on the docs. (The create_user_profile is 100% from the docs).

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    location = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100, blank = False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    private = models.BooleanField()


    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

What's the -proper- way to set and save these fields?

For example, if I have both the User and UserProfile models in one form (in a registration form, for example), how would I first create, then update all of this, before finally saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how would I first create, then update all of this, before finally saving

These aren't separate steps. When you create or update a record in Django, you are saving it to the database.

For the registration form, I'd recommend you set it up as a `ModelForm` on `User` records, then specify the additional fields you want to save to the profile and save them separately in the save function, like so...

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    # etc -- enter all the forms from UserProfile here

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', and other fields in User ]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user = user
        profile.location = self.cleaned_data['location']
        # and so on with the remaining fields
        profile.save()
        return profile
```

Comment: Took me a bit, but this really helped me understand how it all works. Thanks!

Comment: quick question: would you do something like `cd = form.cleaned_data -> form.save(cd)` in order to access the save function?

Comment: No. You just call it as `form.save()` and it has access to the cleaned data already.

Answer (score 0):

You could call profile.user.save() and after it profile.save() when you need to save data from registration form.

Comment: Note that you can only do this if profile is already created as a record and already has a value for user.

Comment: Jordan, probably my explanation is not precise. I talked about this code: http://dumpz.org/101302/